# IOS: CGRect is right, but UIImage flipped

Tags: ios, drawing, cgcontext

I know i have to translate the coordinate system, when drawing. The thing is that when i use:

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(_context, 0.0, _size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(_context, 1.0, -1.0);
```

My rect of the image is flipped, and the image is 'non-flipped', if i dont use the above my image is flipped, and the rect is non-flipped.

Here's my code:

```
CGRectMake(60, 100, image.size.width, image.size.height);
CGContextSaveGState(_context);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
CGContextClearRect(_context, placeholderRect);
CGContextDrawImage(_context, placeholderRect, image.CGImage);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
CGContextRestoreGState(_context);
```

How do i maintain my rect (non-flipped), while the image is flipped?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick may lie in this UIImage method

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)imageRef scale:(CGFloat)scale orientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation
```

Where orientation is one of these :)

```
typedef enum {
   UIImageOrientationUp,
   UIImageOrientationDown,   // 180 deg rotation
   UIImageOrientationLeft,   // 90 deg CCW
   UIImageOrientationRight,   // 90 deg CW
   UIImageOrientationUpMirrored,    // as above but image mirrored along other axis. horizontal flip
   UIImageOrientationDownMirrored,  // horizontal flip
   UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored,  // vertical flip
   UIImageOrientationRightMirrored, // vertical flip
} UIImageOrientation;
```

**Edit: Update**

I just did this simple code sample in a UIView subclass overriding drawrect and it worked perfectly. It doesn't use the UIImage method but works all the same.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

CGContextRef _context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSaveGState(_context);

CGContextDrawImage(_context, CGRectMake(100, 20, image.size.width, image.size.height), image.CGImage);

CGContextScaleCTM(_context, -1.0f, 1.0f);

CGContextDrawImage(_context, CGRectMake(-300, 20, image.size.width, image.size.height), image.CGImage);

CGContextRestoreGState(_context);
```

Comment: So i have to add the line: `UIImage* flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationDownMirrored];` between `CGContextClearRect(_context, placeholderRect);
        CGContextDrawImage(_context, placeholderRect, flippedImage.CGImage);` That doesnt seem to work?

Comment: Are you still flipping the rect? if so don't.

Comment: No, i'm creating a new image, named flipped image, using the UIImage you provided. The image stays the same when i draw with that image

Comment: Try the creating the flipped image outside of UIGraphicsBeginImageContext

Comment: I added an exact code sample that I just verified in a simple example.

Comment: Worth noting that the UIImage `orientation` property only applies when the image is composited, so getting the CGImage property back from the UIImage or inspecting it in the Xcode debugger won't show the modifications.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `CGContextDrawImage` use `[image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];`